# How is $\sqrt{E(X-Y)^2}$ a distance function?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces, expected-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In the context of Hilbert spaces, the following distance or metric is defined: $\delta(X,Y) \:= \sqrt{E(X-Y)^2}$, where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables such that $E(X^2)<\infty$ and $E(Y^2)<\infty$.

I want to show that $\delta(X,Y)$ is a distance function in the (traditional) sense that: $\delta(X,Y) \leq \delta(X,Z) + \delta(Z,Y)$, i.e. it satisfies the triangle inequality, where also $E(Z^2)<\infty$.

It seems like this should be a simple task, but for some reason I get stuck. I tried working with Jensen's inequality:

$\sqrt{E(X-Y)^2} = \sqrt{E(X-Z+Z-Y)^2} \geq \sqrt{[E(X-Z+Z-Y)]^2} = |E(X-Z+Z-Y)|,$

but that didn't help. Could someone please show how/if $\delta(X,Y) \leq \delta(X,Z) + \delta(Z,Y)$?

Comment: To clarify, are you okay using Minkowski's inequality, or do you want a more basic proof?  (personally, even for a more basic proof, I'd just be adapting the proof of Minkowski to $p=2$)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't consider Minkowski's inequality (haven't used it before). Please show how it may be used and I will definitely try to understand it. If there's a more basic proof as well, that would be interesting to see also.

Comment: Are you aware of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$\mathbb{E}[XY]^2\leq\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2] ?$$

Comment: Yes, I have seen the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. That's a good hint and I will try to understand how it can be used here.

Comment: Minkowski for $p=2$ would be $$\sqrt{E[(A+B)^2]} \leq \sqrt{E[A^2]} + \sqrt{E[B^2]}$$ which is what you're proving for $A=X-Z, B=Z-Y$, so it's immediate.  The proof is a pretty standard argument via Cauchy-Schwarz (or Hoelder for general $p$)